# JAVA convert date string into Date Object

Tags: java

I have a string came from an API call. The string is in the formate of `2021-02-12T13:48:15-05:00`.

I want to convert it into java  date object. I try to use `Date.valueOf(..)`, but it throws IllegalArgumentException.

I checked the other posts, seems like I need to specific the format of my string, like `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

But, I am not sure how to format this string. Can I get some help?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: — and `SimpleDateFormat` is even worse. By all means stay away from it.